# Вытаскивание данных из textarea ajax

Tags: ajax, php, textarea

Подскажите, пожалуйста, решение вот к такой задаче:  В `Textarea` много разных слов:

```
Слон
язь
зуб
кость
и т.п.
```

Как  доставать слово по очереди и отсылать с `ajax`. Подскажите

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/QfP36/1/

```
for(var i=0, spTx = document.getElementById('q').value.split("\n"); i < spTx.length; i++) {
    ajax({
        'url':'/',
        'data':spTx[i],
        'type':'post',
        'success': function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```